# Java Interface in InputVerifier

Tags: java, swing, interface, inputverifier

I have this code:

```
 public class Anagrafica implments ClientiInterface{    
 InputVerifier verifierAliquotaIva = new InputVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        boolean verifica = true;
        final JTextComponent source = (JTextComponent) input;
        String text = source.getText();
        if (text.length() != 0){
            String codice = cliente.CercaCliente(text, this);
            if (codice != null){
                verifica = true;
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Codice iva inesistente!");
             tfDescrizioneIva.setText("");
                verifica = false;
            }
        }else{
            tfDescrizioneIva.setText("");
        }
        return verifica;
    }
};
```

}

This is an Clientiinterface. I saw that interface is incompatible within `InputVerifier`. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: If it's an interface, you'll need to create a new class which 'implements' that interface. I'm not able to say anything more, unless you describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: inputverifier is whitn a class that implements a interface

Comment: What error messages are you receiving? What are you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: What do you mean with "I saw that interface is incompatible within `InputVerifier`"?

Comment: the error is: "INCOMPATIBEL TYPE ANIMOUS INPUTVERIFIER CANNOT BE CONVETE cLIENTIiNTERFACE"

Comment: "inputverifier is whitn a class that implements a interface" - it **says** it does, but does it really? Is "ClientiInterface" empty? There is also a typo: "implments" - but I think this is correct in original?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly of what you are trying to achieve, you must use the following:
`public class MyInputVerifier implements InputVerifier { ... }`
instead of this:
`InputVerifier verifierAliquotaIva = new InputVerifier() { ... }`

and then use `new MyInputVerifier()` where needed.

More scientifically, an interface is only a skeleton, it has no implementation. If you want custom code in a place where `InputVerifier` is required, create a class that implements it, and use an instance of your new class

Comment: Sorry for my english, i have this situation: